# One-page website - Including html files into a "master" html

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an one-page website using jQuery. So I thought to have a master index.html file that has all the css/jquery files included and inside that index.html, a div( div id="page" ) where I put all the html from the other pages.

And then I had the following problem: If one of my "sub-pages" that I wanted to include into my index.html, needed javascript, I needed to include all that scripts into that sub-page, not into index.html. This is a big problem because I don't want to include same scripts over and over again in each "sub-page".

I've used $.get function to do this and then an $('...').html(...)
I googled alot searching for a solution, but couldn't find one. Does any one had an idea on how could I do this?

/** EDIT **/
For a better understanding:I'm searching my menu ul li and take all the links from href and put them in an array.After that for each link in that array i'm getting the html code and store it in a variable.

```
    allMenuLinks = ['about','gallery',etc]

    howManyLinksInMenu = allMenuLinks.length;
    $.each(allMenuLinks, function(index, page) {
       $.get("pages/" + page + ".html", function(content) {
           pagesContent[page] = content;
           howManyLinksInMenu = howManyLinksInMenu - 1;
           howManyLinksInMenu == 0 ? changePage() : '' ;
       }, "html")
    })

And on changePage i have $('#page').html(pagesContent[page]) with some animations.
```

Comment: Why not just place all the scripts you need into the top level index.html?

Comment: @Giovanni I have done that but isn't working !! Only if I add the js scripts to that html that needed to be animated for ex. !!

Comment: any chance you could provide us with a live link? You'll get a lot more help this way.

Comment: @michael-giovanni-pumo Again if I want to add a nivoslider, in index.html I add the plugin nivo.slider.js, but If I DON'T CALL the Nivo slider plugin INSIDE my pages/gallery.html, Slider doesn't work!! I want to have inside pages/[page_name].html only the html code, and all the js included only in index.html;

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a templating engine like:

http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: Thank you but i'm not looking for a template engine for php

Comment: Well then the behavoir you eventually build will inevitabley be replicating what is already built through a templating engine.